# Что такое RecNo?

Tags: delphi

Использование `RecNo`:

```
Adottable2.RecNo := node.SelectIndex;
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по имени объекта, `Adottable2` используется компонент `TADOTable`. Он наследник `TDataSet`.
`TDataSet.RecNo` - номер строки результата выполнения запроса в источнике данных.

Answer (score 0):

RecNo - номер записи в наборе данных (будь то таблица (ADOTable, Table) или запрос (ADOQuey, Quey) и т. п.)